# What's the definition of a random number?

Tags: education, random

What sequence of numbers can I call as random number? What's the right way of getting $n$ random numbers?

Are the numbers generated by "dice", too known as random numbers? Can a machine (computer), simulate generation of random numbers like dice in real life?

Comment: I suppose that you mean a fair dice. But there's nothing fair in life, not even dice and coins.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani: Perhaps you can review my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255610/easy-way-to-generate-random-numbers. It would help to know for what purpose you want these (simulation versus cryptography). Regards

Comment: Well, i was browsing through wikipedia, and seen various studies over random number generation. So, just curious, what is so difficult about random numbers. As in real life, it's just a matter of speaking out a number from mouth!

Comment: For some definitions try http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sequence

Comment: It might be interesting to study "random" numbers out of people's mouths.  Obviously, they won't be predictable but I would expect a huge bias towards easy to say numbers.  Depending on your audience, you might get outliers such as googol, googolplex, and maybe even Graham's number.